# convert package name to path

Tags: java

I have a class `de.xyz.MyClass` which is stored in `de/xyz/MyClass.java`.
How can I get this path from the class `MyClass` itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the class"?

Comment: See my answer below; but my question is, what are you *really* trying to do? This feels like a stepping stone, and my suspicion is there's a better way.

Comment: are you trying to load a resource from within this package?

Comment: It is always hard to know with new users/programmers what are they trying to achieve.  Probably not everyone knows that you can **edit** the original question.

Answer (score 24):

Like this:

```
String path = MyClass.class.getName().replace(".", "/") + ".java";
```

But note that sometimes class names are annotated (e.g., inner classes, etc.). More [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

If you're starting with an instance of the class (perhaps `this` inside one of the class's methods), you can get the class via `instance.getClass()`. For instance:

```
private String getPathToThis() {
    return this.getClass().getName().replace(".", "/") + ".java";
}
```

Of course, these are going to be relative to some base (directory or jar) in the classpath...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this answer you question so I'll do my best guess:

```
package de.xyz;

class PathForClass {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        System.out.println( 
            PathForClass.class.getResource( "PathForClass.class" ) 
        );
    }
}
```

Which when compiled and run gives:

```
C:\Users\Oscar\code>javac -d . PathForClass.java

C:\Users\Oscar\code>java -cp . de.xyz.PathForClass
file:/C:/Users/Oscar/code/de/xyz/PathForClass.class
```

That way you can modify a little the calls and have the path as you want:

```
package de.xyz;

class PathForClass {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        String currentDir  = new java.io.File(".").toURI().toString();
        String pathToClass = PathForClass.class.getResource( "PathForClass.class" ).toString();
        System.out.println( pathToClass.substring( currentDir.length() - 2  )); // -2 to get rid of the /./ at the end of the current dir
    }
}

C:\Users\Oscar\code>java -cp . de.xyz.PathForClass
de/xyz/PathForClass.class
```

Bear in mind that will only work where the classes are stored in directories, for jars you'll have to modify it a little bit ( `if( pathToClass.startsWith("jar")){ //etc...` )

Also, class loaders don't always work with the filesystem, some of them load files from databases, ldaps and pretty much anywhere, so is not always true that for `de.xyz.MyClass` there exists a `de/xyz/MyClass.class`  file ( as shown with the jar example)

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Example. In my case I needed the path to a package - `module`, in my classpath. For this I simply did: `AnyClassName.class.getResource("/module").getPath();`. Note that `module` starts with a `/`.

Answer (score 7):

There is an util class  ==>  org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.

```
ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath("de.xyz.MyClass");
```

Source : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html

Comment: Note that the class you mentioned and the documentation you linked to are different classes – one is part of Apache Commons and the other is part of the Spring framework. If you're already using one of those in your project you can use one of those, but otherwise it's a rather heavy dependency to pull in for something simple. In fact, the code for the Spring ClassUtils method you mentioned is basically this: className.replace(PACKAGE_SEPARATOR, PATH_SEPARATOR).

Comment: There is no such method in org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils and link above.

Comment: @AHHP as  jwj mentioned in the comment above, it is a trivial method in the Spring's [ClassUtils](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#convertClassNameToResourcePath).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
```

Comment: This prints `de.xyz.MyClass`. The desired output is `de/xyz/MyClass`.